Ubuntu WiFi issue: rtw_8822bu failed to get tx report from firmware
My PC's Wifi stopped working recently, probably after a kernel upgrade or so. The Wifi connects to the SSID & the port is assigned an IP address. However I am not able to Ping anything apart from the host itself. Tried rebooting, re-connecting, Wifi Router reboot, Disabled GUFW, etc but nothing worked. Everything else is working fine in the LAN.
Tried to add below Grub boot parameter, but it dint helped:
pcie_aspm=off

Changed the below parameter to disable power saving mode, dint helped even - /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf:
wifi.powersave = 3 ==> 2

Changed the Power saving mode in Power management to Balanced, issue still existed.
Wifi Dongle is TP-Link Archer T3U [Realtek RTL8812BU]
I suspect either a bug in kernel or firmware or else hardware issues.
Please guide me to figure out the issue and help resolve if possible.
Below is the output of DMESG command and Wireless-info script:

Dmesg: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/byDJdFx4RZ/
Wireless-info: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/MfwQwKH69W/


I suspect your TP-LINK ARCHER T3U [RTL8812BU] driver is not working for the new kernel.
https://www.tp-link.com/uk/home-networking/adapter/archer-t3u/#overview
Supports Windows 10/8.1/8/7/XP, Mac OS X
Linux?
Your current driver:: Archer T3U [Realtek RTL8812BU] 6.8.0-41-generic (& you are using this kernel) I could not find an TP-LINK ARCHER T3u linux driver for this device.
You could try the driver here. I think yours is on this. (8812bu). However, it will involve working with sources and the ubuntu DKMs (Auto rebuild mechanism for drivers etc).
https://github.com/morrownr
Compatible Kernels
Kernels: 4.19 - 5.11 (Realtek)
Kernels: 5.12 - 6.9 (community support)

You can remove the current driver with the following command
sudo modprobe -r rtw_8822bu

sudo modprobe rtw_8822bu should re-install it
DKMS
Use dkms status to identify the device driver (RTL8812BU) for each succesfully built kernel. Your original driver source could/will have an uninstall to uninstall it. If not then you could uninstall it as follows: -
Typical output of dkms status
rtl8812bu/X.XX.X.X, 6.8.0-41-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812bu/X.XX.X.X, 6.8.0-44-generic, x86_64: installed

Typical removal from the dkms. If it is removed it should also stop the driver installing but you might have to reboot to achieve this. You need to use your details of the driver you have installed but here are are some examples. (Note: Only uninstall from non-active or broken driver kernels.)
dkms remove rtl8812bu/x.x.x.x --all
dkms remove rtl8812bu/x.x.x.x -k  6.8.0-45-generic -a x86_64

installation
Open a gnome-terminal
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade #normal updates
sudo apt install -y build-essential dkms git iw #Tools needed
mkdir -p ~/src #make a directory to place the sources
cd ~/src #move to directory
git clone https://github.com/morrownr/88x2bu-20210702.git #download sources
cd ~/src/88x2bu-20210702 #Move into sources
sudo ./install-driver.sh #(Note to remove it run remove-driver.sh).
If you are running secure boot and you have not installed a mokkey the driver will not get signed so it will not run. The instructions on the site do give some advice regarding this. (In particular the section on manual installation.)
I think it is a good idea to reboot before you starting testing.
To check the driver is installed in the dkms (for auto build when the kernel gets updated) run the following
sudo dkms status

I hope this is of some help
