Connection problems with rtl88x2bu driver?
So have this realtek usb wifi adapter (ID 0b05:184c). Been using it for a few years, but had needed to compile the driver and install via DKMS, since the included ubuntu version was flakey. Needed to do a fresh ubuntu install (22.04), and have been having connection issues (randomly drop connection or have giant packet loss). Realized that this might be an issue again. At the time I compiled the module, I don't think ubuntu had native support. It appears that it does have a driver installed now (rtl88x2bu), but don't know if there's a better one available, or if my issues are unrelated.

The easiest, probably best, choice is to stick with the kernel's driver. Look at the network logs with the terminal command: sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager.  Also do: service NetworkManager status.

Please see the answer at the following location: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1527031/ubuntu-wifi-issue-rtw-8822bu-failed-to-get-tx-report-from-firmware/1527078#1527078 which points to a dkms install version that should covers Kernels: 5.12 - 6.9 (community support) Don't forget to uninstall your current version from the dkms first. There is normally a script to run in the old install.
